# Unable to get list of drop-down options (objects)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all options of drop-down list. But it's returning - []. In actual my dropdown list has 250 options (list of countries)

Following is the contents of my HTML page -

```
<select id="country" selected="" name="country">
  <option value="U0">Unknown</option>
  <option value="AP">Asia/Pacific Region</option>
  <option value="EU">Europe</option
  .
  .
  .
```

To get all options, I wrote following -

```
element = driver.find_element(:id, "country")
countries = element.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
```

but it's returning empty array - [] Actually, it should return array of objects.

Does Selenium fail to return large number of options from drop-down? Or is there anything wrong in HTML page or selenium code?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you published, the following works.
I suggest you add options to the html-file until you get the error.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require 'ap'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get("file:///c:/ruby193/test/selenium/test.html")
element = driver.find_element(:id, "country")
countries = element.find_elements(:tag_name, "option") 
ap countries

# [
#     [0] #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4033eddc id="{87044904-9da3-4194-9440-b585e9dabfc2}">,
#     [1] #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f2be9452 id="{6692657d-df40-4dd5-a8ad-a2dbadda18b5}">,
#     [2] #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fb1e0e416 id="{8886c68e-5c4f-45a5-8220-4795a73cabbe}">
# ]
```

Here is test.html

```
<select id="country" selected="" name="country">
  <option value="U0">Unknown</option>
  <option value="AP">Asia/Pacific Region</option>
  <option value="EU">Europe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually, I created test page for drop-down with 250 country options. When I ran the code (as we discussed above) against test page, it's listing all objects. But when I run same code with my website to automate, it's returning empty array - []. I'm not getting what's wrong going on. Thanks, Peter for the help.

Comment: Then can you publish the url of your website ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was my fault. I ran those commands on irb & it was returning []. But when I write script & stored in a file & ran that file then it listed all objects of options of drop-down.

Looks irb puts limitation to array range.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use default select class to get all options available in drop down list ?

Select Class : [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/Select.html)

Get Options method : [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/Select.html#options-instance_method)